# Somando resultados

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria

Estou começando a usar o *framework* [uaiCriteria](http://uaicriteria.com/) e preciso de um resultado que é uma somatória de registros num período.

Algo como (simplificado):

```sql
select sum(valor), sum(desconto), data, idpessoa from tabela group by data, idpessoa
```

Fiz:

```
UaiCriteria<Despesa> uc = UaiCriteriaFactory.createQueryCriteria(getEntityManager(), Despesa.class);
uc.sum("valor").sum("desconto").groupBy("data","pessoa");
```

Esperava que ele me retornasse uma coleção de objetos (`Despesa`) com os atributos totalizados. mas ele me retorna apenas um objeto `Despesa` com o valor de apenas um dos objetos.

Comment: Temos o [criador/pai desse framework aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/544/uaihebert), não sei se marcando o mesmo aqui ele será notificado, mas não custa tentar. @uaiHebert.